# center legend with margins alined with plot panel

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to center my legend, so it's the same width as the plot panel. I got is quite close, as in the next MWE

```
ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_col(aes(x = cyl, y = mpg, fill = as.factor(am))) +
  theme(
    legend.text = element_text(
      size = 13,
      vjust = 0.5, hjust = 0.5
    ),
    legend.text.align = 0,
    legend.direction = "horizontal",
    legend.background = element_blank(),
    legend.title=element_blank(),
    legend.key = element_blank(),
    legend.key.width = unit(0.7, "cm"),
    legend.key.height = unit(0.35, "cm"),
    legend.position = "top",
    # legend.justification = c(0.5),
    legend.justification = "left",
    legend.spacing.x = unit(0.5, "cm"),
    legend.box = "horizontal",
    legend.box.just = "center",
    # legend.box.margin = margin(t = 0, r = 500, b = 0, l = 500, unit = "null"),
    legend.box.margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 0.05, l = 0, unit = "npc"),
    legend.margin = margin(t = 0.01, r = 1, b = 0.01, l = 1, "npc"),
    legend.box.background = element_rect(fill = c("#f2f0f2"), colour = NA),
    legend.box.spacing = unit(0.1, "lines"),
    complete = T
  ) +
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = NA))
```

I added annotations to the result, which shows that this MWE

1. Doesn't align with the main plotting area
2. The legend's elements are not centred

[image]

How would you fix these?

Update 2022-07-01: I added the solution by @TarJae and it doesn't work for wider plots, where I want the legend to cover from the y axis to the and of the plotting area at the right side.

```
ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_col(aes(x = cyl, y = mpg, fill = as.factor(am))) +
  theme(
    legend.text = element_text(
      size = 13,
      vjust = 0.5, hjust = 0.5
    ),
    legend.text.align = 0,
    legend.direction = "horizontal",
    legend.background = element_blank(),
    legend.title=element_blank(),
    legend.key = element_blank(),
    legend.key.width = unit(0.7, "cm"),
    legend.key.height = unit(0.35, "cm"),
    legend.position = "top",
    legend.spacing.x = unit(0.5, "cm"),
    legend.box = "horizontal",
    legend.justification = "center",
    legend.margin = margin(t = 0.01, r = 1, b = 0.01, l = 1, "npc"),
    legend.box.background = element_rect(fill = c("#f2f0f2"), colour = NA),
    legend.box.spacing = unit(0.1, "lines"),
    complete = T
  ) +
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = NA))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We could do it by hand: `p` is your plot:

```
p +  theme(legend.justification = "center",
        legend.margin = margin(t = 0.2, r = 24.4, b = 0.2, l = 24.4, unit = "cm"))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! Iḿ trying to use npc because then I have to save with different dimensions as png